# How can I manage partitions on Windows 7 Install?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

On my home desktops I have an SSD as a primary disk, then a larger SATA disk as a secondary. The thing is, when I install Windows 7 on the SSD, the 100MB "System Reserved" system partition is built on the secondary SATA disk rather than the SSD. When I last built my machine I physically unplugged the secondary disk before installing Windows 7 to get around this.

I've also tried using Diskpart from the Windows install PE to delete any partition and filesystem on the secondary drive but one is created on there anyway.

See below:
[image]

Disk 0 is the 500GB SATA disk, while Disk 0 is the 120GB SSD. Is it because the secondary disk is Disk 0?

How can I change this, either from within Windows or during setup?

Comment: To save lots of time and hassle I'd just unplug the HDD each and every time I re-install Windows. Additionally you could pre-partition the SSD before installing Windows. Using this method will cause Windows 7 to not create the 100/200MB System Reserved partition (it puts the boot files in the main C drive partition). Search for install windows without reserved partition.